# Adb can't see my device - PAP5400

Tags: adb, windows, usb-debugging, debug

When I connect my Prestigio PAP5400 DUO to my PC, ADB cant find it.

[image: adb screenshot]

I think the driver is wrong but I can't find right one. I have tried installing many drivers.

PS: I have debugging mode activated. I'm using Windows 8.1.

PPS: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your device manager is showing that the adb drivers are not properly installed. If properly installed there would be no question mark by the left of the icon.

I found the following steps in this article [here](http://blog.itfiser.cz/android-adb-with-prestigio-multipad-pmp5080cpro-and-win7/)

1. First of all you have to Enable the USB Debugging in the Developer settings.
2. Connect your tablet to the computer USB port.
3. Select MTP connection instead of Mass Storage (you can find it at Storage -> USB computer connection)
4. Right Click on Computer->Manage->Device Manager,  search for PMP5080C and update driver with Google USB Driver.
5. Download [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html). In program search "PMP5080 C PRO USB Device" and remember the Vendor ID for me it was 0x2207.
6. Open %UserDir%.android\adb_usb.ini a write there the Vendor ID (2207) without the leading 0x.
7. Open command line at %android_sdk%\platform-tools\
8. adb kill-server
9. adb start-server
10. adb devices

Now the adb devices will display your device.

Answer (score 0):

ADB will not automatically connect to your device when it is plugged in. The "Devices" command will give you a list of "connected" devices, not devices available for connection.

To connect your device issue the command: `adb connect localhost`

Let me know if I misunderstood your situation or if there is anything else I can do to help.

Comment: when i use "adb connect localhost" adb show "unable to connect to localhost:5555"